# How to force enable a task in build definition

Tags: azure-devops

I created a task extension in azure devops and I wanted to force all build definitions to use it.  Is there a way to prevent users not to disable the task?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you need to restrict the ability to edit a build definition, you can use security groups and assign permissions at the build definition level. There is no mechanism to restrict the ability to modify individual tasks.